# Visual Studio Setup Fail 2015

Tags: visual-studio, exe, fatal-error

I've been looking on the net and can't find a solution to this. No one had the same issue as I had. So a couple of days ago I uninstalled everything that had to do with microsoft visual c++ so I can start fresh. Little did I know that by doing this would create a big mess for me when I tried to install Visual Studio Community 2015. This is the error I got! Please help. I also reinstalled the software Microsoft Visual C++ x64 but still it didnt work.

[image]

Here is some change log
[image]

Comment: clock on the "log" link and post the logs

Comment: Instead of an image of a part of log file why not just giving us the whole log file? Then we could have the whole thing, and even search for text in it. Delete the image and add the text (format it as code).

Comment: Also, did you try just to install what the setup is [telling you it's missing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)? (both x86 and x64)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found out a solution but its not the best one because I still run into areas where I have to skip certain files because the installer cant find them. All I did was clean out %temp% files and then ran the application downloader as admin. Then it worked just fine. Now I'm not sure how it will effect visual studios as a whole but at least I can build a project.

Answer (score 0):

Download the .ISO file for Visual Studio, extract its contents, and then run the setup file. I have found this can fix a wide variety of errors, so it might be worth a shot.